# Structuring a Rails CMS type application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I've just finished going through my first book learning RoR and wanted to practice some more extending the project, but I'm at a bit of a loss for how to structure the additions I want to make and would appreciate some guidance.

Right now the application is separated by pages that have a model controlling the logic and a controller routing that logic to the view, but none of the pages have any cross-over in features. I want to create a page that has pre-templated features with logic from other models, sort of like widgets in WordPress, or plugins in Magento. If I had a Page model and wanted to inject a Bestsellers list in the view, or I had a Blog model and wanted to inject a list of products with a tag calling out to a template with all the markup already, what is the proper way to do this?

Would these have to be modules? Would I just create another view template for Catalog that I would call into the Page index view?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer to what I was looking for [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)